# Java 8 group by and summing in List<List<String>> object

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `List<List<String>>` containing a table values to be outputted in csv.

```
id|name|rank|count
1|aaa|A1|2
2|aaa|A0|1
3|bbb|A2|5
4|bbb|A1|3
5|ccc|A|2
```

I want to group by 2nd element in the list(name in the above example) and sum the count field. Expected output as below.

```
name|count
aaa|3
bbb|8
ccc|2
```

What is the best way to achieve this in Java 8? Please advice.

Comment: take a look at `toMap` and `mergeFunction` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html

Comment: I would suggest to use a csv parcer

Comment: .. and then look into `Collectors.groupingBy` with `Collectors.summingInt` with Java. (exactly as your title reads)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your required:

```
String[] lines = {
        "1|aaa|A1|2",
        "2|aaa|A0|1",
        "3|bbb|A2|5",
        "4|bbb|A1|3",
        "5|ccc|A|2"
};
List<List<String>> data = Stream.of(lines)
                                .map(e -> Arrays.asList(e.split("\\|")))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
Map<String, Integer> result = data.stream()
                                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.get(1),
                                                            e -> Integer.valueOf(e.get(3)),
                                                            Integer::sum)
                                  );
System.out.println(result);
```

But better if you parse the csv to Pojo object.

Comment: Look into `Collectors.groupingBy` with `Collectors.summingInt`